# Best practice to add script to users script/startup directory

Tags: python, path

I'm making an addon that when loaded adds a script to the users scripts/startup directory but I have several options when doing this and want to know the "best practice".

`bpy.utils.script_path_user()` returns the users scrips path which I could simply append "/startup" to, and this works fine on Linux (my OS) and I'm assuming Mac as well, but this will not work on Windows. I could find the operating system we're running on and have a `if` statement take care of it using the correct slash.
Is this a good way? Or is there a more elegant way of getting the correct dir?

`bpy.utils.script_paths(subdir="startup", user_pref=True, check_all=False, use_user=True)` returns a list of options, 2 in my case, one of which **is** the perfered location `'/home/ash/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/startup'` but I cannot be sure which position in the list it will be (or can I??) I also have no idea how this behaves in Windows, and can't test it.

Is the first approach fine? Or is there a better way?